# Slow ApplicationSettingsBase

Tags: c#, concurrency, application-settings

The application settings mechanism (derived from ApplicationSettingsBase) seems to be a real bottleneck when used in multithreading scenarios. Especially, when properties are queried often, the concurrency they introduce is slowing down my loops. I like to use them anyway to have those nice application configuration option. But maybe I need to wrap them into my own cache or so?

Anyone having the same issue? Am I missing something? I thought, the ApplicationSettingsBase does cache all settings already? Why does it seem to lock access from multiple threads at all? What could be a common workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see annything strange in having a thread safe settings mechanismm? If it is slowing your hihgly concurrent theads down, you should try to use local variables istead of querying the getsetting fast again. I think a redesign of your settings request mechanism would help performmance considerably.

Comment: I suppose you are right. The settings mechanism seems not to be intended for such usage scheme. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really suggest wrapping any sort of "get settings" functionality in an object and hiding it behind an interface.  We strongly-type this, so we have:

```
public class Worker 
{
    private readonly ISettings settings;
    public Worker (ISettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public void Work ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < settings.MaxWorkerIterations (); i++)
        { ... }
    }
}

public interface ISettings
{
    int MaxWorkerIterations ();
}

public class AppConfigSettings
{
    public int MaxWorkerIterations ()
    {
        return (int) ApplicationSettings["MaxWorkerIterations"];
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of (mostly) compile-time checking and easy testability.  You can also override your AppConfigSettings class to be a CachingAppConfigSettings class that does the obvious.

Comment: I dont really see your point. How would this improve the situation? But due to the lack of other qualified answers, I will have to accept your solution anyway. ;)

Comment: Yippie!  A pity accept!  What about my answer isn't helpful?  I mentioned a few upsides to this and how you can easily add a caching layer.

Comment: Its not helpful, since wrapping the settings in an interface would not get rid of the performance problems described in the question. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: " You can also override your AppConfigSettings class to be a CachingAppConfigSettings class that does the obvious." ?